# How can I make a RadioButton NOT inflate programmatically in a custom adapter?

Tags: android, custom-adapter

All,

I have a custom adapter that is used for inflating quiz questions/answers into a ListView. Each question (single item in the ListView) have a variable number of answers, (but a max number of answers (5) is static).

In addition to populating each RadioButton's text (using setText) with an answer string, I would like to use my custom adapter to evaluate whether all RadioButtons in the RadioGroup has an answer associated with it and inflate it (or not) accordingly. Ideally, I'd like to "un-inflate" a RadioButton or the equivalent effect programmatically because I am able to evaluate answer validity in the custom adapter.

I've tried `radioButton.setHeight(0)` and `radioButton.setMaxHeight(0)` with no luck.

The xml resource file I pull answerStrings from is defined as so:

The answer xml resource file stores all answer strings in a single string-array with an assumption of 5 answers per questions for indexing purposes. 
Valid answers are represented by a non-empty item in the string-array. no valid answer is represented by an empty item stub.

```
<string-array
    name="answer_array">

    <!-- question 1 answers -->
        <item>question 1 answer A</item>
        <item>question 1 answer B</item>
    <item>question 1 answer C</item>
    <item>question 1 answer D</item>
    <item>question 1 answer E</item>

    <!-- question 2 answers --> 
    <item>question 2 answer A</item>
    <item>question 2 answer B</item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>

<!-- question 3 answers -->
        <item>question 3 answer A</item>
    <item>question 3 answer B</item>
    <item>question 3 answer C</item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>

</string-array>
```

**My quiz layout file is as follows:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="4dip"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- quiz question -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"  
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"/> 

        <!--  answers for each question -->
        <RadioGroup 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/A_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="doNothing"/> 

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/B_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="doNothing"/>   

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/C_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="doNothing"/> 

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/D_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="doNothing"/>   

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/E_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                    android:onClick="doNothing"/>

        </RadioGroup>   

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Inside my custom adapter, I am trying to do the following;**

```
private ViewHolder initRadioButtonText(ViewHolder holder, Custom quiz_row_data) {

    /* check if valid answer */
    int length = (quiz_row_data.getA_AnswerString()).length();

    if(length == 0) {
        holder.A_button.setHeight(0);
        //holder.A_button.setMaxHeight(0);
    }
    else
            holder.A_button.setText(quiz_row_data.getA_AnswerString());

    /* ..... etc etc for the other answer buttons ..... */

    return holder;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A_button` is the button you don't want to show then just use

```
holder.A_button.setVisibility(RadioButton.GONE);
```

This will completely remove it from the `layout` until you call

```
holder.A_button.setVisibility(RadioButton.VISIBLE);
```

If you aren't worried about removing it to make room for other `View`s then use

```
holder.A_button.setVisibility(RadioButton.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: This worked great for removing a specific Button from the layout programmatically. Thank you codeMagic. I should also note for other users looking at this answer; that the visibility of each button needs to be set explicitly despite being used independently for question ie: itemholder.D_button.setVisibility(RadioButton.VISIBLE) in addition to setting the RadioButton text

Comment: Glad I could help! That's why my second block was in there but I guess I could have explained it better...good note! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to change the button height to zero, the correct way would be to use `LayoutParams`:

```
holder.A_button.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));
```

Otherwise, the second solution would be to toggle the Visibility as codeMagic showed.